# Return index of nearest values in an array

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var scores=[0.7, 1.05, 0.81, 0.96, 3.2, 1.23];
```

What's the more readable way to return the indexes of the nearest values to another variable?

For instance:

With variable = 1  Should return `{ low: 3, high: 1 }`

Comment: Iterate over the array, compare values and record indices? If by "best" you mean something more elaborated, maybe build an interval tree? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: less elaborate, but simple. i was trying Array.reduce returning an object but could not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost as simple but faster (O(n)) than sort:

```js
const nearest = (arr, n) => arr.reduce((r, x) => ({
  lo: ((x < n) && (x > r.lo) ? x : r.lo),
  hi: ((x > n) && (x < r.hi) ? x : r.hi)
}), { lo: -Infinity, hi: Infinity })

const mapIndexOf = (obj, lookup) => Object.keys(obj).reduce(
  (a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: lookup.indexOf(obj[v]) }), {}
) 

const scores = [0.7, 1.05, 0.81, 0.96, 3.2, 1.23]

console.log(mapIndexOf(nearest(scores, 1), scores))
```

Answer (score 2):

Slow `(O(n*log(n))` and simple:

```js
const nearest = (arr, val) => (sorted => (indexOfVal => ({
  lo: sorted[indexOfVal - 1],
  hi: sorted[indexOfVal + 1]
}))(sorted.indexOf(val)))([...arr, val].sort())


const mapIndexOf = (obj, lookup) => Object.keys(obj).reduce(
  (a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: lookup.indexOf(obj[v]) }), {}
) 

const scores = [0.7, 1.05, 0.81, 0.96, 3.2, 1.23]

console.log(mapIndexOf(nearest(scores, 1), scores))
```

Comment: Isn't it rather `O(n + log(n))` which is basically `O(n)`.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed that sort has `O(n*log(n))` and search has `O(log(n))` complexity; thus, `O(n*log(n) + log(n)) = O((n+1)*log(n)) = O(n*log(n))`. If I am wrong about sorting, please share your source.

Comment: Oh of course. I don't know why I thought sorting had the (basically) impossible runtime of `O(log(n))`. Time to go to sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array, subtract the value from your variable, compare, then record the closest values.  Here's a quick example:

```js
var value = 1;
var scores = [0.7, 1.05, 0.81, 0.96, 3.2, 1.23];
var ret = {};

for(var i = 0, len = scores.length; i < len; i++){
  var comp = scores[i] - value;
  if(comp > 0){
    if(!ret.high){
      ret.high = i;
    }
    else if(scores[i] < scores[ret.high]){
      ret.high = i;
    }
  }
  else if(comp < 0){
    if(!ret.low){
      ret.low = i;
    }
    else if(scores[i] > scores[ret.low]){
      ret.low = i;
    }
  }
  else{
    ret = {
      low: i,
      high: i
    };
    break;
  }
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'high: '+ret.high+' low: '+ret.low;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
var lower = function(a,b){return a.element > b.element ? b : a; };
var higher = function(a,b){return a.element > b.element ? a : b; };
var withIndex = function(element,index){ return {element: element, index: index}; };
var nearest = function(array, limit) {
  var lowerValues = array.map(withIndex).filter(function(a){ return a.element<limit });
  var higherValues = array.map(withIndex).filter(function(a){ return a.element>limit });
  return {
    low: lowerValues.reduce(higher).index, 
    high: higherValues.reduce(lower).index
  };
}
```

Comment: What exactly makes this the "best" way?

Comment: Is the most elegant way to do it, although I have some ideas to improve it

Answer (score 0):

```
var scores=[0.7, 1.05, 0.81, 0.96, 3.2, 1.23];
var lowIndex = 0;
var highIndex = 0;
var currentLow = 0;
var currentHigh = 0;
var temp = 0;
var variable = 2;
for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
{
    temp = variable - scores[i];
    if((currentLow == 0) && (temp > 0))
    {
        currentLow = temp;
    }
    if((currentHigh == 0) && (temp < 0))
    {
        currentHigh = temp;
    }
   if((temp >= currentHigh) && (temp <= 0))
   {
      highIndex = i;
      currentHigh = temp;
   }
   if((temp <= currentLow) && (temp >= 0))
   {
      lowIndex = i;
      currentLow = temp;
   }
}
window.alert("Low:" + lowIndex + "  High:" + highIndex);
```

This code works and you can see the logic of whats going on.

Comment: Why would you downvote the correct answer. Who downvoted this?

Answer (score -1):

```
// for storing greater values and their indeces   
var gtVals = {
    val : [],
    ind : []
};

// for storing lesser values and their indeces 
var ltVals = {
    val : [],
    ind : []
} 

var scores=[0.7, 1.05, 0.81, 0.96, 3.2, 1.23];

function highLow(value){
     var val = parseFloat(value);

         for(var i = 0; i < scores.length ; i++){
            if(scores[i] > val ){
                gtVals.val.push(scores [i] - val );
                gtVals.ind.push(i );
           }
        else{
             ltVals.val.push(val - scores[i] );
             ltVals.ind.push(i );
         }

     }
    var higherindex = gtVals.ind[gtVals.val.indexOf((Math.min.apply(Math, gtVals.val)))];
    var lowerindex = ltVals.ind[ltVals.val.indexOf((Math.min.apply(Math, ltVals.val)))];
    return {
        low: lowerindex,
        high :  higherindex
    };
}

console.log(highLow(1));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2q572hxj/3/

Answer (score -1):

For people who love perl, assembler or regular expressions, here a solution near to a single-liner:

```
var compV = 1;
var scores=[0.7, 1.05, 0.81, 0.96, 3.2, 1.23];

for(var h=0,l=0,i=0,tmp=0,lV=Number.MAX_VALUE,hV=lV; i < scores.length; i++) {
   tmp=compV-scores[i];tmp>0 && tmp<lV ? (l=i,lV=tmp) : tmp<0 && -tmp<hV ? (h=i,hV=-tmp) : 0; }
```

l (lowercase "L") holds the index of the lowest value, h (lowercase "H") holds the index of the highest value. Have fun :)

Comment: I would like to know the same

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: Thank you, this is a very helpful information. It would be a good idea, to make all voters visible (up/down) by a mouseover bubble to avoid behavior like this on beforehand.

Comment: @f6a4: Voting is (and will always be) anonymous.  The system can (and does) detect serial voting.  It's automatic.

Comment: Thank you all for the information. I'm new here and still not familiar with the voting mechanism. But I'll learn it, hopefully. ;)

Comment: FYI, `var h=l=i=tmp=0` is evaluated as `var h=(l=(i=(tmp=0)))`, i.e. it creates a *local* variable `h` and the *global(!)* variables `l`, `i` and `tmp`.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for the hint, sometimes I mix up the differnt capabilities of programming languages.